# Is there a way to iterate through a 2d list where it'll access the elements in order by first index, second, etc

Tags: java, arraylist

```
    List<List<Integer>> myList = new ArrayList<>(3);

    for(int i=0; i < 3; i++) {
        myList.add(new ArrayList());
    }

    myList.get(0).add(1); // 0,0
    myList.get(0).add(4);           //0,1

    myList.get(1).add(2); // 1,0
    myList.get(1).add(5);           // 1,1

    myList.get(2).add(3);// 2,0
    myList.get(2).add(6);           //2,1
    myList.get(2).add(7);                   //2,3

    for(int i =0; i<myList.get(i).size(); i++){
        for(int j=0; j<myList.size(); j++){
                System.out.println(myList.get(j).get(i));
        }
    }
```

I cant figure out how to iterate through the list on a index based, with different lengths on each list. My code above only works if all lists are the same size.

Ideal output would be:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7

But I cant figure out how to print out 7 since that list is a different length. This might be a very simple solution and ill probably feel dumb after. Thanks guys

Comment: Just swap your for loop exit conditions -- and use the correct subscripts in your println

Comment: For these problems, it is always a good idea to do them on paper first. Sketch it out, figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To iterate over all elements of List of Lists you need to iterate in the first `for`-loop over the outer List, and in the second `for`-loop over the inner loop at that index. There are several possibilities to achieve the iteration over all elements, as you will see in the following examples.

(Your code would also produce a `IndexOutOfBoundsException` for the last entry).

##### Iterating through a List of Lists

**Option 1 (your code corrected)**

```java
for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) { // i represents index of outer List
    for (int j = 0; j < myList.get(i).size(); j++) { //j represents index of the inner list at index i
        System.out.println(myList.get(i).get(j));
    }
}
```

---

**Option 2 (using for-each loop)**

```java
for (List<Integer> innerList : myList) {
    for (Integer currentPosition : innerList) {
        System.out.println(currentPosition);
    }
}
```

---

**Option 3 (using streams)**

```java
myList.stream()
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

---

##### Edit due to comment: added traverse method for wanted output

If you want to print out all first entries of the inner lists first, a possibility would be to traverse your `List<List<Integer>>` with a method like this (method is generic, would also work with other classes):

```java
private static <T> List<List<T>> traverse(List<List<T>> input) {
    List<List<T>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < input.get(i).size(); j++) {
            if(result.size() <= j) {
                result.add(new ArrayList<>());
            }
            result.get(j).add(input.get(i).get(j));
        }
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

In your method then just create a new `List<List<Integer>>` like this and iterate over this new list of lists:

```java
List<List<Integer>> myListTraversed = traverse(myList);
```

Comment: Im sorry I think didnt explain it properly. Im trying to not iterate just over the lists, rather print them such as it will print all the index 'i' of every list such as if list a has 123 and list b has 456 , the output would be 1->4->2->5->3->6  instead of 1->2->3->4->5->6. So index 1 of both lists first, then index 2 of both list and so forth.  Except not all list are the same size.

Comment: I added a method to my answer, which should help you to get your desired output. It will traverse your array, so it will create a new `List<List<Integer>>` where the inner lists contain the elements collected by the indexes of your other list. Hope this helps.